# Remove a string that does not have a number after of it?

Tags: r, regex, string

How can I remove strings that are not succeeded by numbers?

For example, I am working with string data like the one below:

```
String <- c("NA; ab 1917; ajr 69; sb 700; sb 703; scarl m; ab 1672 a",
"ab 18 sb 5 ab 1433 hdge; ab 1129 ab 184 ab 473 a",
"ab 3 16 31 41 1134 1206 abuht",
"ab 479 862 984 1626 asc")

df <- data.frame(String)
```

I would like the output to look like the following:

```
Output <- c("NA; ab 1917; ajr 69; sb 700; sb 703;; ab 1672",
"ab 18 sb 5 ab 1433 ab 1129 ab 184 ab 473",
"ab 3 16 31 41 1134 1206",
"ab 479 862 984 1626")

df <- data.frame(String, Output)
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. What would you recommend?

Comment: Number munchin?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: You don't seem to be using a consistent rule for removal, rather several, that are not mutually exclusive

Comment: @TedLyngmo The link takes me to a google results page that has nothing to do with coding, strings, or regex. So I'm confused about the link's purpose. Additionally, I still do not understand what "number munching" means. Do you mean number matching?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm so sorry. I don't understand what you are trying to communicate to me.

Comment: I'm out. Sorry for interrupting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that works for the data as posted:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(
    Output = gsub("\\s[A-Za-z]+(\\s[A-Za-z]+|;)|\\s[A-Za-z]+$", "", String))
                                                   String                                        Output
1 NA; ab 1917; ajr 69; sb 700; sb 703; scarl m; ab 1672 a NA; ab 1917; ajr 69; sb 700; sb 703;; ab 1672
2        ab 18 sb 5 ab 1433 hdge; ab 1129 ab 184 ab 473 a      ab 18 sb 5 ab 1433 ab 1129 ab 184 ab 473
3                           ab 3 16 31 41 1134 1206 abuht                       ab 3 16 31 41 1134 1206
4                                 ab 479 862 984 1626 asc                           ab 479 862 984 1626
```

The regex proceeds in two steps (or alternations):

- `\\s[A-Za-z]+(\\s[A-Za-z]+|;)`: first alternation to match the alphabetic strings that are either followed by another alphabetic string or a `;`
- `|`: alternation marker
- `\\s[A-Za-z]+$`: second alternation to match the remaining alphabetic strings at string end

Answer (score 2):

Using an ide like vscode or notepad++, I can use this to match `(\s)([a-z][a-z][a-z]+)` and replace with this`$1`.

Your need is confusing as according to your output, 'ajr' is not supposed to be matched meanwhile 'asc' is matched. My hack above matches both 'ajr' and 'asc'.

A breakdown of my hack is:

1. `(\s)` matches the space before the group of letters. I noticed that you want to match only group of letters found after a space.
2. `([a-z][a-z][a-z]+)` matches groups of letters greater than 2 (as I noticed that you do not want to match 2 letter groups).
3. `$1` replaces the match with the nothing.

I hope it helps. You can take this and translate it into the programming language you are using and there.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I couldn't add my comment so I wrote my insufficient code here.

I agree with Chris's opinion.

I focused on "Output"'s first line and tried using ";" as the separator.

If you want to add the separator " "(white space), just modify the code.

```
String <- c("NA; ab 1917; ajr 69; sb 700; sb 703; scarl m; ab 1672 a",
"ab 18 sb 5 ab 1433 hdge; ab 1129 ab 184 ab 473 a",
"ab 3 16 31 41 1134 1206 abuht",
"ab 479 862 984 1626 asc")
res<-c()
for(str in String){
    hoge<-strsplit(str, ";")[[1]]
    res<-c(res, paste(hoge[grep("\\d|NA", hoge)], collapse=";"))
}
# ** this result is insufficient **
data.frame(res)
                                               res
1   NA; ab 1917; ajr 69; sb 700; sb 703; ab 1672 a
2 ab 18 sb 5 ab 1433 hdge; ab 1129 ab 184 ab 473 a
3                    ab 3 16 31 41 1134 1206 abuht
4                          ab 479 862 984 1626 asc
```

If you Edit your question, kind contributers will help you I think.

Comment: So, don't take it to a data.frame right away. You've achieved keeping the annoying 'NA' and dropping the strange 'scarl m', `res2 <- sub('\\D+$', '', res, perl = TRUE)` gets us most of the way there. `res3 <- sub(' hdge;', '', res2, fixed = TRUE)` then `res4 <- sub('703;', '703; ;', res3, fixed = TRUE)`, at which point it is prudent to ask the OP (question asker) why they'd want  a `;  ;` in their result...Feel free to add to your answer. Often it take several steps to figure out how to get to 'desired results' before you can make it a one-liner, if such is possible, even.

Answer (score 1):

First let's determine the regex:

```
succeed_num_regex = "(( )?.+ [0-9]+)+"
```

The meaning:

- `( )?`: we allow (but don't require) a space at the beginning
- `.+`: some amount of free text (this is the "string" that is to be succeeded by a number)
- : there must be a space after the string
- `[0-9]+`: this is the number
- The whole thing is enclosed in `()+`, meaning that we are looking for this pattern to repeat one or more times.

Now we can put this in code:

```
library(tidyverse)
String %>%
  str_split("; ") %>%
  map(map_chr, str_extract, pattern = succeed_num_regex) %>%
  # Strings that did not have this pattern at all will be NA
  # We replace them here with ""
  map(map_chr, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), "", x)) %>%
  # Put it all back together
  map_chr(paste, collapse = "; ")

[1] "; ab 1917; ajr 69; sb 700; sb 703; ; ab 1672"
[2] "ab 18 sb 5 ab 1433; ab 1129 ab 184 ab 473"   
[3] "ab 3 16 31 41 1134 1206"                     
[4] "ab 479 862 984 1626"
```

Some notes:

- In your output, you kept `"NA"` instead of it getting replaced with `""`, which is what later happened to `"scarl m"`. This can be added as a rule to the solution, but for now I did not add it because it is not consistent with your requirements.
- In your output, the second result `"ab 18 sb 5 ab 1433 ab 1129 ab 184 ab 473"` is missing a semi-colon after `1433`. If that was not a mistake, then please explain why.
- In your output, we have `sb 703;;` whereas my output has `sb 703; ;`. This is to be consistent that the results are pasted with `"; "`. Let me know if this is problematic (I left it as is since that isn't a clear requirement either).